# input field created by jquery not posting data

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form shown below which is bit large:

```
   <form method="post" action="{{ url('/page/save') }}" class="pageForm">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class="box-body">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Page-Title:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="page_title" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Page Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Page-Alias:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="page_alias" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Auto-Generated If Left Blank">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Add Image</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Use Image Of 840 X 320 For Better Resolution" name="page_image" value="" type="text" id="page_image">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #3C8DBC">
                <a style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="BrowseServer('page_image');" >
                    <span style="color: #FFF;">Select Image</span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--  Page Type  -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select-Type:</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 10px;" class="page_type" name="page_type" value="single_page">Individual Page
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 10px;" class="page_type" name="page_type" value="post_page">Post's Page
    </div>

    <!-- Post Type  -->
    <div class="form-group" id="postSelect" style="display: none;">
        <label>Select-Post:</label>
        <br/>
        <select id="allPosts" value="" name="page_postParent" class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select Post For Page </option>
            <option value="8">About Us</option>
            <option value="10">Blog</option>
            <option value="12">Day Tour</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Adding menu to navigation -->
    <div class="form-group" id="singleMenuNav" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Enter Menu Title for page:</label>
            <input type="text" id="page_navTitle" name="page_navTitle" value="" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Add-Menu To:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 10px;" class="menuLocation" name="nav_location[]" value="mainMenu">Main Menu
            <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 10px;" class="menuLocation" name="nav_location[]" value="footerMenu">Footer Menu
            <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 10px;" class="menuLocation" name="nav_location[]" value="subMenu">Sub-Menu
            <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 10px;" class="menuLocation" name="nav_location[]" value="category">Add To Category
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sub-Menu List -->
    <div class="form-group" id="menuSelect" style="display: none;">
        <label>Select-Menu:</label>
        <br/>
        <select id="allMenus" value="" name="page_menuParent" class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select Parent Menu For Page </option>
            <option value="8">About Us</option>
            <option value="12">Contact Us</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Category List -->

    <div class="form-group" id="categorySelect" style="display: none;">
        <label>Select-Category:</label>
        <br/>
        <select id="allMenus" value="" name="page_menuParent" class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select Category For Page </option>
            <option value="1">Nepal</option>
            <option value="2">Bhutan</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Template Type -->
    <div class="form-group" id="template" style="display: none;">
        <label>Template:</label>
        <br/>
        <select id="templateOption" value=" " name="page_template" class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select Template For Page </option>
            <option value="generic">Generic Page</option>
            <option value="itinerary">Itinerary Page</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
<!--End of row-->
<!-- Generic Content -->

<div class="row" id="genericContent" class="pageTemplate" style="margin-top: 40px; display:none;">
    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Generic Page</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Page Content:</label>
                <br/>
                <textarea name="page_content" class="editor form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End of primary box-->
    </div>
    <!--End of col-md-12-->
</div>
<!--End of row-->

<!-- Individual Pages -->

<div class="row" id="itineraryContent" class="pageTemplate" style="margin-top: 40px; display: none;">
    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <h3 class="box-title">Itinerary Page</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <hr/>
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Trip Excrept</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="editor" name="trip_excrept"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End of box body-->
        </div>
        <!--End of primary box-->

        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Trip Information </h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Trip PDF</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Upload The Trip PDF" name="trip_pdf" value="" type="text" id="trip_pdf">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #3C8DBC">
                            <a style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="BrowseServer('trip_pdf');" >
                                <span style="color: #FFF;">Select Image</span>
                        </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Trip-Starting Price:</label>
                    <input type="number" value="" name="trip_price" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip's Starting Price">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Trip-Price Info:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="trip_priceInfo" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip's Price" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Trip-Duration:</label>
                    <br/>
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Min-Days</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_duration[]" />
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Max-Days</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_duration[]" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Total-Persons:</label>
                    <br/>
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Min-People</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_person[]" />
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Max-People</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_person[]" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Trip-Accomodation Type:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="trip_accomodation" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip Accomodation" />
                </div>

                <div class=" form-group ">
                    <label>Trip-Transportaion:</label>
                    <input type="text " value=" " name="trip_transport " class="form-control " id=" " placeholder="Enter Transportation Info ">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Map-Guide:</label>
                    <input type="text " value=" " name="trip_mapGuide " class="form-control " id=" " placeholder="Enter URL To Trip 's Map">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Trip-Fooding:</label>
                    <br/>
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Breakfast</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_fooding[]" />
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Lunch</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_fooding[]" />
                    <em style="margin: 10px;">Dinner</em>
                    <input type="number" name="trip_fooding[]" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End of box body-->
        </div>
        <!--End of primary box-->
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">Trip Highlights*</h3>
                <div style="float: right; color:3C8DBC;">
                    <span><h6>*Min-Trip Highlights: 3</h6></span>
                    <span><h6>*Total Trip-Highlights Must Be Multiple Of 3</h6></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">

                <!-- Trip Highlights Div-->
                <div id="tripHighlights">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Trip-Highlight Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="trip_highlightTitle[]" class="form-control clearHiglights" id="highlightTitle" placeholder="Enter Trip Highlight's Title ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label>Trip-Highlight Image</label>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <input class="form-control clearHiglights " placeholder="Upload Image For The Highlight " name="trip_highlightImage[] " value=" " type="text " id="trip_highlightImage ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon " style="background: #3C8DBC ">
                                <a style="cursor: pointer; "  onclick="BrowseServer( 'trip_highlightImage'); " >
                                    <span style="color: #FFF; ">Select Image</span>
                            </a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <button id="addMoreHighlights " class="btn ">Add-More</button>

                <!-- End Of Highlights Trip-->
            </div>
            <!-- End of box body-->
        </div>
        <!--End of primary box-->
    </div>
    <!--End of col-md-12-->
    <button type="submit " style="margin: 10px; " class="btn btn-primary ">Create Page</button>
</div>
<!--End of row-->
```

`

The Trip Highlights Div at the end of my form will get dynamically generated using jquery, using following code

```
 var i=1;
                    $('#addMoreHighlights').on('click',function(event){
                        //prevent default action
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var clone = '<div data-count="'+i+'" ><br/><hr/><div class="form-group" ><label>Trip-Highlight Title:</label><input type="text" value="" name="trip_highlightTitle[]" class="form-control clearHiglights" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip Highlight\'s Title"></div><div class="form-group"><label>Trip-Highlight Image</label><div class="input-group"><input class="form-control clearHiglights" placeholder="Upload Image For The Highlight" name="trip_highlightImage[]" value="" type="text" id="trip_highlightImage"><span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #3C8DBC"> <a style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="BrowseServer("trip_highlightImage");" ><span style="color: #FFF;">Select Image</span></a></span></div></div><button style="float: right; margin: 5px;" data-removeCount="'+i+'"class="removeMoreHighlights btn">Remove</button></div>';

                        $('#tripHighlights').append(clone);
                        i++;
                    });
```

When I do so and submit the form the data in the input fields created dynamically will not be submitted only the initially present inputs fields data get submitted, but when I create a seperate form for the Trip Highlights Div and use same jquery code the post data contains data from input fields dynamically generated too. What is the problem here. The post data I get when I submit this form is

```
'trip_highlightTitle' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'title 1' (length=7)
  'trip_highlightImage' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image1' (length=6)
```

but this is what I want

```
'trip_highlightTitle' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'title 1' (length=7)
      1 => string 'title 2'  (length=7)
  'trip_highlightImage' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'image2'  (length=6)
```

Comment: DOM ids shoud be unique in `var clone` `id=""` and `id="trip_highlightImage"`, maynot solve your problem just to notice

Comment: wont solve my problem but thanks for heads up@cske

Comment: Make sure your HTML code validates first of all.